# pd.read_csv add column named "Unnamed: 0

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a dataframe with 3 columns.
I save with `pd.to_csv(filename)`
and then re-open it with

```
pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=False)
```

But I get a dataframe with 4 columns, with the left-most column called

> Unnamed:0

that is actually just the row number.
How can I read the csv without it?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the first 2-3 lines (including the headers) of the CSV file and the expected dataframe (if you can't share the actual data then dummy data in the same format is sufficient)

Comment: While you should really provide sample data, Im guessing what you want is to add `index=False` to `pd.to_csv`

Comment: @okuoub, can you provide the initial  lines of the code .

Comment: @okuoub , see the answer , mostly that should cover your problem, if that helps then you can upvote or even accept an an answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should try:

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv', index_col=0)
```

> index_col : int or sequence or False, default None Column to use as
>   the row labels of the DataFrame. If a sequence is given, a MultiIndex
>   is used. If you have a malformed file with delimiters at the end of
>   each line, you might consider index_col=False to force pandas to not
>   use the first column as the index (row names)

**Example Dataset:**

I have taken the dataset from google,So while i'm simply trying to import the data with pd.read_csv it shows the `Unnamed: 0` as default.

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv("amis.csv")
>>> df.head()
   Unnamed: 0  speed  period  warning  pair
0           1     26       1        1     1
1           2     26       1        1     1
2           3     26       1        1     1
3           4     26       1        1     1
4           5     27       1        1     1
```

So, Just to avoid the the `Unnamed: 0` we have to use `index_col=0` and will get the nicer dataframe:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv("amis.csv", index_col=0)
>>> df.head()
   speed  period  warning  pair
1     26       1        1     1
2     26       1        1     1
3     26       1        1     1
4     26       1        1     1
5     27       1        1     1
```

*Note* : So, to make it more explicit to understand when we say `index_col=0`, it placed the first column as the index in the dataFrame rather appearing as `Unnamed: 0` .

Hope this will help.