# How to read in csv with to to a DASK dataframe so it will not have “Unnamed: 0” column?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dask, dask-dataframe

**Goal**

I want to read in a csv to a DASK dataframe without getting “Unnamed: 0” column.

**CODE**

```
mydtype = {'col1': 'object',
           'col2': 'object',
           'col3': 'object',
           'col4': 'float32',}


do = dd.read_csv('/folder/somecsvname.csv', 
                 dtype = mydtype, 
                 low_memory=False,
                 parse_dates=['col3'],
                )
```

**Result Columns**

- Unnamed: 0
- col1
- col2
- col3
- col4

**Tried solutions**

- 1.works with pandas not with dask - [pd.read_csv add column named "Unnamed: 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53988226/pd-read-csv-add-column-named-unnamed-0)
- 2.works with pandas not with dask - [How to get rid of "Unnamed: 0" column in a pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36519086/how-to-get-rid-of-unnamed-0-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe)
- CODE added to read in: `index_col=False` ERROR message: `ValueError: Keywords 'index' and 'index_col' not supported. Use dd.read_csv(...).set_index('my-index') instead`
- CODE added to read in: `index_col=0` ERROR message: `ValueError: Keywords 'index' and 'index_col' not supported. Use dd.read_csv(...).set_index('my-index') instead`
- CODE that recommended by previouse 2 error messages-> DISFUCTION: this just sets up a value as an index but still generates that 'Unnamed: 0' column

```
do = dd.read_csv('/folder/somecsvname.csv', 
                 dtype = mydtype, 
                 low_memory=False,
                 parse_dates=['col3'],
                ).set_index('col3')
```

- CODE added to read in: `index_col=None`  ERROR message: `ValueError: Keywords 'index' and 'index_col' not supported. Use dd.read_csv(...).set_index('my-index') instead`
- CODE added to read in: `index_col=None, header=0` ERROR message: `ValueError: Keywords 'index' and 'index_col' not supported. Use dd.read_csv(...).set_index('my-index') instead`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that this column (`Unnamed: 0`) is present in the original csv file. It's best to address it upstream, at the time this file is generated. If that's not possible, then the best you can do with `dask.dataframe` is:

```py
ddf = dd.read_csv(my_file)
ddf = ddf.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1)
```

Here's a reproducible example:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(range(5))
df.to_csv('abc.csv')

ddf = dd.read_csv('abc.csv')
ddf = ddf.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1)
```

Comment: Yep so currently this is how I solve it, but it would be great if it wouldn't even create the column and that is the goal of the post.

Comment: Yes, that's not possible with `dask.dataframe`. You could achieve something similar with `delayed`, but it's really not worth it, because of the introduced code complexity.

Comment: Add `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: @DarrenWeber: AFAIU, `.reset_index` would work if `Unnamed: 0` was used as the index column by `dd.read_csv`. However, the [current API doesn't allow specifying an index column](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.read_csv.html).

Comment: I mean, after the `ddf.drop(...)`, I found it useful to reset the index after computing the pandas DataFrame i.e.: `df = ddf.compute().reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: I see, that's definitely useful to get unique index for df that fit into memory, however for large dfs this might not be feasible.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add these 2 combnations in the read_csv function:

```
index_col=None
index_col=None, header=0
```

Comment: it have given the same error message but thx.